# How to implement rollbar into a expressionengine setup?

Tags: php-errors, bestpractice

I'm talking about [http://rollbar.com](https://rollbar.com/)

> Rollbar collects and analyzes errors on web and mobile apps so you can
>   find and fix them faster.

What would be the best approach to get this working?
Is it possible to hook into the EE logging itself?

I would like to log things like:

- 404 pages
- errors while sending mail (freeform)
- module/plugin php errors (what super-admin's get to see)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

First you would need to to decide which integration method you would like to use probably either PHP, API or JS. With the data you want to collect you would probably be best to use the PHP or API integrations ([PHP link](https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar-php/) or [API link](https://rollbar.com/docs/api_overview/)). From there you have a few options:

1. Write an extension (my recommendation)
2. Modify the index.php file to include the PHP script on every page load.

[EE's Add-on Developer Docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html) should get you started in the right direction on creating an extension.